# Does one fulfill Mishloach Manos by giving food to someone that the sender can eat but the recipient can’t, or vice versa?

Tags: food, purim, mishloach-manot

Consider the following cases:

1. Reuven is deathly ill. He is instructed by doctors to eat pork in order to save his life, so, obviously, he does. But Shimon is a healthy individual and therefore cannot eat pork.
2. Shimon is deathly allergic to peanuts, but Reuven has no problem with them.

Can Shimon give the pork or nuts to Reuven? Since Reuven can eat them, is it okay, or since Shimon cannot eat them, is it a problem?

What about the opposite case, where Shimon is able to eat them but Reuven is not?

What if Shimon asks Levi to give the Shaloch Manos? Does Levi have to be able to eat the foods?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a person allergic to nuts can send someone else nuts if _he_ can eat them, as we always go by what is considered food by most people e.g tumas ochlin, rather than what people personally eat. Sending someone nuts to eat unbeknownst to him when he is severely allergic might kill him so it's a Mitzvah haba baaveira which probably doesn't count just like shaking a stolen lulav on second day Succos.